# How to set my Child Layout also starts from parent's position?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I try to set my LinearLayout starts from screen edge(like Parent layout).I dont want the White Space between two layouts.
i need to start from left side from screen edge and top also edge . or follow the parent left and top properties.

**NOTE:
suppose i dont want to change the Relative layout properties only changes in linear layout means how to fix it?**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.zd.MainActivity" >


 <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:id="@+id/preview" 
      android:focusable="true">
       <requestFocus />

  </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I think you know what is PADDING and why we use.

Comment: now update the question

Answer (score 0):

remove these lines.. these are creating padding for the child.

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

But according your question.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/gray"

    android:clipToPadding="false" // this will do the trick here

    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    // suppose you have 16dp padding
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="-16dp" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="-16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-16dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/preview"
        android:background="@color/green"
        android:focusable="true">
        <requestFocus />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: suppose i dont want to change the Relatievlayout properties only changes in linearlayout means how to fix it?

Comment: the padding you are using on top... just use the same padding with negative sign in your LinearLayout... i didn't tried.. u can give it a try.

Comment: try putting `android:clipToPadding="false"` in parent layout. see the edits.

Comment: dude... the code above is tested.. can you show me your code.

Comment: is it posssible to set android:clipToPadding="false" at run time??

Comment: yes but i said "without chnaging relative layout codes"

Comment: your code working but i can change the relative layout but i dont want that

Comment: for runtime you have to access it by id,,,but, that is also a modification in relative layout.

Comment: as you commented on above answer... the parent layout is not urs.. one thing i would like to clear you. "Padding is not by default unless you define it".

Comment: and one more pblm is if change the "LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);" at run time also does not affect anything in UI . .Why

Answer (score 0):

DO LIKE BELOW.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.zd.MainActivity" >


 <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:id="@+id/preview" 
      android:focusable="true">
       <requestFocus />

  </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: suppose i dont want to change the Relatievlayout properties only changes in linearlayout means how to fix it?

Comment: then its not possible.

Comment: thats the must bro . .

Comment: what an issue if you change in RelativeLayout?

Comment: northg issue . . but the layout is dynamic so i dont know exact layout everything from run time and client side. for example i just put relative layout but its not conform one. Thats why i am asking as per PARENT layout position